# Python Pandas DataFrame extract data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python. How can I save only the codes for each category ? For A it would be:

```
code31
code2321
code135821
```

I want to save that in a csv file for each category, e.g. A.csv

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['A', 'code31'], ['A', 'code31323'], ['G', 'code641'], ['F', 'code641'], ['A', 'code2321'], ['F', 'code253'], ['A', 'code135821'], ['G', 'code2318']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Category', 'Code'])
print(df)
```

```
Category        Code
0        A      code31
1        A   code31323
2        G     code641
3        F     code641
4        A    code2321
5        F     code253
6        A  code135821
7        G    code2318`
```

Can I the unique() function, maybe: df.unqiue() ?

Comment: Why `code31323` is missing for A?

Comment: Why code31323 is missing for A

Comment: `df['Code'].to_csv("file_name.csv")` will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to iterate over your categories and export data:

```
for cat, codes in df.groupby('Category')['Code']:
    codes.to_csv(f'{cat}.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

`A.csv`:

```
code31
code31323
code2321
code135821
```

`F.csv`:

```
code641
code253
```

`G.csv`:

```
code641
code2318
```